# sqoop import from oracle fails

Tags: oracle, hadoop, sqoop

i have an error while offloading oracle table to hdfs, here is the command:

```
sqoop import -Dmapreduce.job.queuename=root.username \
--connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@//someExadataHostname/dbInstance \
--username user \
--password welcome1 \
--table TB_RECHARGE_DIM_APPLICATION \
--target-dir /data/in/sqm/dev/unprocessed/sqoop/oracle_db_exa_test \
--delete-target-dir \
--m 1
```

it throws an error:

```
Warning: /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.10.1-1.cdh5.10.1.p0.10/bin/../lib/sqoop/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
18/01/10 14:27:24 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6-cdh5.10.1
18/01/10 14:27:24 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
18/01/10 14:27:24 INFO teradata.TeradataManagerFactory: Loaded connector factory for 'Cloudera Connector Powered by Teradata' on version 1.5c5
18/01/10 14:27:25 INFO oracle.OraOopManagerFactory: Data Connector for Oracle and Hadoop is disabled.
18/01/10 14:27:25 INFO manager.SqlManager: Using default fetchSize of 1000
18/01/10 14:27:25 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
18/01/10 14:27:29 INFO manager.OracleManager: Time zone has been set to GMT
18/01/10 14:27:29 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM TB_RECHARGE_DIM_APPLICATION t WHERE 1=0
18/01/10 14:27:29 INFO orm.CompilationManager: HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME is /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hadoop-mapreduce
Note: /tmp/s/compile/926451c21b6a6623f9763b96c7afa503/TB_RECHARGE_DIM_APPLICATION.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
18/01/10 14:27:31 INFO orm.CompilationManager: Writing jar file: /tmp/compile/926451c21b6a6623f9763b96c7afa503/TB_RECHARGE_DIM_APPLICATION.jar
18/01/10 14:27:32 INFO tool.ImportTool: Destination directory /data/in/sqm/dev/unprocessed/sqoop/oracle_db_exa_test deleted.
18/01/10 14:27:32 INFO manager.OracleManager: Time zone has been set to GMT
18/01/10 14:27:34 INFO manager.OracleManager: Time zone has been set to GMT
18/01/10 14:27:34 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Beginning import of TB_RECHARGE_DIM_APPLICATION
18/01/10 14:27:34 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.jar is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.jar
18/01/10 14:27:34 INFO manager.OracleManager: Time zone has been set to GMT
18/01/10 14:27:34 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.map.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.maps
18/01/10 14:27:34 INFO hdfs.DFSClient: Created token for username: HDFS_DELEGATION_TOKEN owner=username@company.CO.ID, renewer=yarn, realUser=, issueDate=1515569254366, maxDate=1516174054366, sequenceNumber=29920785, masterKeyId=849 on ha-hdfs:nameservice1
18/01/10 14:27:34 INFO security.TokenCache: Got dt for hdfs://nameservice1; Kind: HDFS_DELEGATION_TOKEN, Service: ha-hdfs:nameservice1, Ident: (token for username: HDFS_DELEGATION_TOKEN owner=username@company.CO.ID, renewer=yarn, realUser=, issueDate=1515569254366, maxDate=1516174054366, sequenceNumber=29920785, masterKeyId=849)
18/01/10 14:28:10 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Slow waitForAckedSeqno took 33367ms (threshold=30000ms). File being written: /user/username/.staging/job_1508590044386_4156415/libjars/commons-lang3-3.4.jar, block: BP-673686138-10.54.0.2-1453972538527:blk_3947617000_2874005894, Write pipeline datanodes: [DatanodeInfoWithStorage[10.54.1.110:50010,DS-bfb333fb-f63f-4c85-b60f-3ce0889fe16d,DISK], DatanodeInfoWithStorage[10.54.0.187:50010,DS-5c692f55-614c-4d33-9e83-0758d2d54555,DISK], DatanodeInfoWithStorage[10.54.0.183:50010,DS-8530593e-b498-455e-9aaa-b1a12c8ec3b2,DISK]]
18/01/10 14:28:13 INFO db.DBInputFormat: Using read commited transaction isolation
18/01/10 14:28:14 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
18/01/10 14:28:14 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1508590044386_4156415
18/01/10 14:28:14 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Kind: HDFS_DELEGATION_TOKEN, Service: ha-hdfs:nameservice1, Ident: (token for username: HDFS_DELEGATION_TOKEN owner=username@company.CO.ID, renewer=yarn, realUser=, issueDate=1515569254366, maxDate=1516174054366, sequenceNumber=29920785, masterKeyId=849)
18/01/10 14:28:15 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1508590044386_4156415
18/01/10 14:28:15 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: https://host:8090/proxy/application_1508590044386_4156415/
18/01/10 14:28:15 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1508590044386_4156415
18/01/10 14:28:28 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1508590044386_4156415 running in uber mode : false
18/01/10 14:28:28 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
18/01/10 14:29:38 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1508590044386_4156415_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.setDbConf(DBInputFormat.java:170)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.setConf(DBInputFormat.java:161)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:73)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:749)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1920)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.getConnection(DBInputFormat.java:223)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.setDbConf(DBInputFormat.java:168)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:673)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:715)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:385)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:30)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:564)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBConfiguration.getConnection(DBConfiguration.java:302)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.getConnection(DBInputFormat.java:216)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:445)
    at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:464)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:594)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:229)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1360)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:486)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.connect(TcpNTAdapter.java:162)
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnOption.connect(ConnOption.java:133)
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:411)
    ... 24 more
```

i am able to list the table using

```
sqoop list-tables --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@//someExadataHost/dbInstance --username user --password pass
```

i dont know why the network cant established connection but it successfully launching the job (it means sqoop able to connect and identify oracle table is exist right?). the map task never finished so..

any idea about this? thank you

Comment: Can you check if firewall connectivity is open from the host you are trying the host where job is getting submitted.

Comment: hi @SandeepSingh , i'm able to telnet destination host, (i think firewall is allowing connection between sqoop and oracle), any other advice?

Comment: have your run it with the --verbose option?

Comment: @shainnif yup, the output still same, its just adding a lot of library in the log..

Comment: potentially a red herring but have you checked that the  tnsnames.ora on the task host is configured for that host?

Answer (score 0):

There might be many reasons you are facing this issue:

- The listener is not configured properly
- The listener process (service) is not running.Re-start it with the
  `lsnrctl start` command or on Windows by starting the listener
  service.
- Also please check the hostname in oracle net manager and
  listener.Both should be same.Path (Local -> service naming -> orcl)

Hope this helps!!

Comment: hi @Subash our DBA says there is nothing wrong in the listener, thus the exadata is for production env..

Comment: Could you try using ip instead of a host name.

Comment: yup, i've tried that too, the result it's still the same, i'm able to list all table in the oracle database, but unable to import or export it.. really confused now..

Comment: But as per the logs its related to DB connection.Could you check whether you have installed oracle connector jar file.If not please do so by copying  Sqoop lib folder (/usr/lib/sqoop/lib).http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-112010-090769.html

Comment: The reason for you to be able to list the tables is, sqoop list tables job will not run the map reduce job. I would suggest adding the verbose and see what query is the sqoop job creating and running on oracle. If you see something is not good in the query that sqoop job is generating, use —query and write your select query there.

Comment: hi @Subash , the library didnt exist in /usr.lib.sqoop/lib , do i need to add the ojdb.jar?

Comment: hi @rob i did adding the verbose argument, but still it doesn't give any important information, mostly the verbose just writing library included in sqoop..

Comment: Yes please add the jar and try running the sqoop statement

Comment: @galih Did you tried looking for the logs in yarn for the particular failure node ? That will give you some more stack of the error, CLI will not provide the complete stack..

Comment: @Subash will try, need to contact sysadmin first, i will inform you the result

Comment: @rob okay then, i need to contact our cloudera admin first since i didnt have access to map reduce logs, i will inform you the result later

Answer (score 0):

Add --driver oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver to the command line.